# Split Recurring Subscription Payments (paypal or other gateway)

Tags: wordpress, paypal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

Me and a partner sell SaaS and are trying to split recurring monthly payments from our customers.

Paypal Payouts seems to only work on initial payments, not recurring, and paypal have decommissioned their adaptive payment methods.

We were considering Stripe, but since I am in the US and he is in the Philippines it will not work from his end.

Any ideas on how we can get these recurring monthly payments split between us?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to build a Stripe Connect integration.  It should be one Platform Account (that represents your joined business; it will need a business account) and two Standard Accounts that represent each of you as individuals.  Unfortunately, since your partner is in the Phillipines, they'll need to get a bank account in a country that is supported by Stripe Merchants.

https://stripe.com/global

You might also be able to leverage Stripe Atlas here.

https://stripe.com/atlas

Hope that helps!